# How to use collection_check_boxes with one to many association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two models:

```
create_table "owners", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.string   "image"
  t.text     "description"
end

create_table "dogs", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.string   "age"
end
```

Now when I want to create owner I have a form for @owner and there are already @dogs in database so they need to be displayed in form and submitted together when owner is created. I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
<%= f.collection_check_boxes :owner, :dog_ids, Dog.all, :id, :name %>
```

I receive this error:

```
undefined method `merge' for :name:Symbol
```

How can I display those dogs in a form and send them in a form? Thank you!

Comment: try: `<%= f.collection_check_boxes :dog_ids, Dog.all, :id, :name %>`

Comment: @WaliAli, now it says there is no such a method :dog_ids

Comment: try to define a method in the dog model for retrieving the name and use that instead of :name
*def get_name/self.name/end*,

Answer (score 0):

Also if you are using rails 4, you need to permit dog attributes in your owner's controller as:

```
def owner_params
  params.require(:owner).permit(dog_ids:[])
end
```

Comment: Thank you but that above solution doesn't work for me. What could I be doing wrong?